# Determine the set X

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A=\{\,2013^{30n^2+4n+2013}: n \in \mathbb{N}\,\}$. Let $X$ be the set of remainders when dividing all numbers in $A$ by $21$. Determine the set $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$2013\equiv-3\pmod{21}$$

$$(-3)^1\equiv-3\equiv18,(-3)^2\equiv9,(-3)^3\equiv-27\equiv15\pmod{21}$$
$$(-3)^4=81\equiv18$$

So, the cycle begins

$$\text{Now, }30n^2+4n+2013\equiv n\pmod 3$$

Comment: can you tell me the set of X or what number in X

Comment: @user109019,  it should be $\{18,9,15\}$